# Does _ReadWriteBarrier Ensure Visibility of Dynamically Allocated Buffers Across Threads?

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, memory-barriers

I am using Visual C++ and Windows 7 and XP. I have two threads in a program where, after both are created, one thread dynamically creates a buffer and assigns its address to a global pointer, then writes data to that buffer. Will a call to _ReadWriteBarrier guarantee the visibility of that data to the second thread?

For example:

```
char *buff;
HANDLE EventObject;

main()
{
    // Create an event object so we can signal the second thread
    // when it is time to read the buffer.

    EventObject = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

    // Create the second thread.

    CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadProc, NULL, 0);

    // Allocate the buffer.

    buff = (char*)malloc(100);

    // Write some data to the buffer.

    buff[50] = rand() % 256;

    // Set the fence here.

    _ReadWriteBarrier();

    // Signal the other thread that data is ready.

    SetEvent(EventObject);

    // Go on our merry way in this thread.
    .
    .
    .
}

ThreadProc(void* p)
{

    // Wait for the signal that data is ready.

    WaitForSingleObject(EventObject, INFINITE);

    // Read the data written to the buffer.

    printf("%d\n", buff[50]);
}
```

I believe from the [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/f20w0x5e%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that `_ReadWriteBarrier` guarantees the visibility of the address in `buff`, as `buff` is a global variable. But does it also guarantee the visibility of the *buffer itself*, that was created in `main`? Is it even necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `SetEvent`, you don't need to have the barrier at all. The event takes care of that.

Usually, for barriers to have a visible effect, you need them on both sides (the writing and the reading side). Since `SetEvent`/`WaitForSingleObject` both act as barriers, you're fine.

Comment: That's great info! Can you point me to some doc that confirms it? I've been digging and digging in the MSDN pages on this and can't find anything on it, other than the barrier calls themselves. Remarkably, Microsoft's closest example (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686915(v=vs.85).aspx)) doesn't show the actual access to memory, so I am wondering if it even has to be global (as would seem to be required [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/f20w0x5e(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Ah, found it! It's a bit oblique, but it is [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686355%28VS.85%29.aspx). stackoverflow.com is kind of amazing, sometimes. Found it by searching for a related question which I found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967852/does-waitforsingleobject-serve-as-a-memory-barrier). I wish they'd be a little more explicit about dynamically allocated space, though... Anyway, thanks! Marking your answer as accepted.